# How do I call variables with similar names using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
var projectNumbers = [];                      
projectNumbers.push(project0[0]);       
projectNumbers.push(project1[0]);       
projectNumbers.push(project2[0]);      
projectNumbers.push(project3[0]);     
projectNumbers.push(project4[0]);        
projectNumbers.push(project5[0]);
```

This adds 6 different numbers from other arrays to the projectNumbers array.

However, I want the code to automatically add numbers to the projectNumbers array based off the number of projects. I tried doing this using:

```
var projectNumbers = [];   
for (var i=0;i<projects.length+1;i++{      
projectNumbers.push("project"+i+"[0]")
}
```

but this ended up displaying `project0[0], project1[0], project2[0]` etc. instead of getting the values of these and displaying 0,1,2 etc.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you have variable names like this, though? if you modify the code when you're assigning values to these variables, that would be a more elegant solution

Comment: Consider first building an array of the arrays in a loop so you end up with... `theArrays = [ project0, project1, ...]`, then loop theArrays pushing the first element of each.

Comment: how are you getting the project items? ie project1 => project5  I think depending on how you are being supplied with this a double array might be best  for instance project[0]0] then you would just write  projectNumbers.push(projects[i][0])  your issue is that you are treating a string as a variable name, you cannot do that.  ( if you use my idea, keep in mind your numbering, arrays start at zero so the project1 would actually be project[0][0] )

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval like this.

```js
eval(`projectNumbers.push(project${i}[0])`);
```

[**Don't do that.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#:~:text=eval()%20is%20a%20dangerous,permissions%20of%20your%20webpage%20%2F%20extension.) You already have a projects array. Does that contain the information from project1, project2... ? If it does then you can just do

```
projectNumbers = projects.map((item) => {return item[0]});
```

If it doesn't you should make an array to contain your projects, then do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments that this seems a bit odd. You could achieve what you want by using `eval()`, but you shouldn't:

```js
projectNumbers.push(eval("project"+i+"[0]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to determine a variable name dynamically.

While there is a way to do this with `eval()`, it's a bad idea, as it opens up code to malicious hacking.

```js
let project0 = [1,2,3];
let val = eval('project' + '0' + '[1]');
console.log(val); // 2
```

If you really want to access names dynamically, you could alternatively store them as properties in a object:

```js
let myObj = {
  project0: ['zero'],
  project1: ['one'],
  project2: ['two']
}
```

Then, since object properties are strings, you can access them easily:

```
let i = 0;
let pName = 'project' + i;
let project = myObj[pName];
console.log(project[0]); // 'zero'
```

Finally, you can loop through the properties in `myObj` to form your desired result:

```js
let projectNumbers = [];
for (let i = 0; myObj["project"+i]; i++) {
  projectNumbers.push(myObj["project"+i][0])
}
console.log(projectNumbers);  // [ 'zero', 'one', 'two' ]
```